# Implies does not return true for a equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, testing-and-verification

**Check the Edited too, please**:
i have a simple equation which i expect to get TRUE from Implies but it just returns the same thing to me. Implies works well for easier examples but I have some more complicated equations need to verify. please help me if yu know:

```
FullSimplify[Implies[xP == x + 1 && yP == y - 1 , x + y == xP + yP]]

the output:
1 + x != xP || x + y == xP + yP || y != 1 + yP
```

I need to verify some quations like this if implies to TRUE of FALSE. what could be the alternative if Implies does not works for these type of calculations? thanks

**EDITED**

based on good answers below, I tried my another equations. I see that for this new equation **With** works and **Resolve[Implies[...]]** does not work. So is there something wrong with my implies? i need to know any consequences around this because I have too many equations like these.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, xP, y, yP},Implies[xP == x + 1 && yP == 2*y ,  y/(2^x) == yP/(2^(xP))],Integers]] 

output:
    (x,y,....) xP == 1 + x && yP == 2 y \[Implies] 2^-x y == 2^(1 - xP) y
```

But With makes it True

```
With[{yP = 2*y  , xP = x + 1},  y/(2^x) == (yP)/(2^(xP))]
True
```

Comment: Why not the simple `With[{xP = x + 1, yP = y - 1}, x + y == xP + yP]` which returns `True`?

Comment: @bmf that's great answer but could you see my edited. really appreciate

Comment: I just saw the edited comment. Not sure what to add, since what I suggested works fine. You might be interested in knowing that `Resolve[ForAll[{x, xP, y, yP}, 
  Implies[xP == x + 1 && yP == 2*y, y/(2^x) == yP/(2^(xP))]]]` yields `True` for your second expression.

Comment: And of course, this `Resolve[ForAll[{x, xP, y, yP}, 
  Implies[xP == x + 1 && yP == 2*y, 
   y/(2^x) == yP/(2^(xP))]], Integers]` also gives `True` if you want to insist on `Integers`

Comment: I had syntax error in my equation which I found by compaing with yous. thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you need to be a bit careful with all the brackets. Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ForAll` quantifier does the job:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{xP, yP, x, y},   Implies[xP == x + 1 && yP == y - 1, x + y == xP + yP]]]
```

> `True`

Comment: that works great for it, but could you see my Edited. really appreciate

Answer (score 3):

I want to summarize all I learned here and my mistake for second equation. both function Implies and With works, my **mistake** for my second expression was putting **Integers inside the ForAll**, so the right answer is below:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, xP, y, yP},Implies[xP == x + 1 && yP == 2*y ,  y/(2^x) == yP/(2^(xP))]],Integers]
```

Also With works same.

```
With[{yP = 2*y  , xP = x + 1},  y/(2^x) == (yP)/(2^(xP))]
```